# save a canvas locally in IE javascript

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, canvas, execcommand

Hi I want to save a canvas locally in IE with execCommand("SaveAs"). Here is my code.

```
 var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");     
 window.win = open (img);
 setTimeout('win.document.execCommand("SaveAs")', 1000);
```

However when new window opened the page cannot be displayed. data:image/octet-stream;base64...
How can I solve this problem? 
Thank you very much...

Comment: Assuming you're talking about IE9, then I don't see any reason to do the `.replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");`. Does removing that change anything?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `window.open` wrong. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.open)

You want

```
  var win = window.open(),
      img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")

  win.document.body.innerHTML= "<img src='" + img + "'></img>" // With correct delimiters
  win.document.close()
  setTimeout('win.document.execCommand("SaveAs")', 1000);
```

Comment: Good advice however doesn't help. at the new window there is no picture. I think the problem is base64 encoding.

Comment: Sorry, updated answer, I forgot `win.document.close()` . Should work now.